# deleting jars from ivy resolved libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, ivy, conflicting-libraries

I have two jars that conflict in my libraries in the java build path. Both of them are resolved by ivy, so I see them inside an ivy.xml entry on the libraries tab. I can't delete anything inside the ivy.xml entry, eclipse only lets me delete the entire entry. Deleting the jar from the source folder is'nt viable either, since I don't have the access rights for that.

Could you give me some advice on how to solve this conflict?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `exclude` in your ivy file, eg.:

```
    <dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.17" conf="default" >
        <exclude module="javaee-api"/>
        <exclude module="geronimo-jms_1.1_spec"/>
    </dependency>
```

You can use following `ant` task to create dependency report:

```
<target name="report" >
    <delete dir="report"/>
    <mkdir dir="report" />
    <ivy:resolve type="${ivy.resolve.types}"/>
    <ivy:report todir="report" />
</target>
```

Comment: Is there a way to find out which jar belongs to which dependency so I know where to use exclude? Unfortunately the names in the ivy file don't really help.

Comment: @Peter The HTML report generated by the ivy "report" task will tell you this.